# How to configure Struts to work with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, struts

Could you please suggest me the best possible answer to this question for a telephonic interview.
            I tried to dig through the forums but couldn't find a detailed answer.
            Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Something tells me that you won't be able to fool an interviewer with anything you learn from this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way round.  You configure Spring to work with Struts like [this](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html).

Comment: Hi duffy, I cant see any link in your post :)

Comment: Hi duffymo, I was waiting for some replies. I know how to accept an answer but I have no idea how to vote it up? Can I accept multiple answers?

Comment: Click on the "up" arrow to vote up.  You'll see the number increment by one.  And you can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Spring framework in Struts2. You just define appropriate types in your Struts action class constructor and plugin will retrieve appropriate bean from Spring's web app context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eugene. Could you please tell me the name of this plugin?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.9/docs/spring-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides some support out of the box:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/struts/DelegatingActionProxy.html

Comment: I believe this is for Spring 1.x only

Answer (score 0):

1. Spring comes with Struts-specific **“spring-struts.jar”** solution for access beans declared in the Spring Ioc container.
2. Register a Spring’s ready-make Struts plug-in in the Struts configuration file.
3. Change your Struts action class to extend the Spring’s `ActionSupport` class, a subclass of the Struts Action class.
4. The `ActionSupport` provide a convenient `getWebApplicationContext()` method for you to access beans declared in Spring Ioc container.

[source](https://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-integration-example/)